# How to have vim highlight color change for the pattern under cursor?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to have the search highlight text in vim under the cursor have a different color compared to the search text not under the cursor?

Answer (score 2):

my `.vimrc` has this codes:

```
function! HiInterestingWord(n) " {{{2
    " Save our location.
    normal! mz
    " Yank the current word into the z register.
    normal! "zyiw
    " Calculate an arbitrary match ID.  Hopefully nothing else is using it.
    let mid = 77750 + a:n
    " Clear existing matches, but don't worry if they don't exist.
    "silent! call matchdelete(mid)
    try
        call matchdelete(mid)
    catch 'E803'
        " Construct a literal pattern that has to match at boundaries.
        let pat = '\V\<' . escape(@z, '\') . '\>'
        " Actually match the words.
        call matchadd("InterestingWord" . a:n, pat, 1, mid)
    endtry
    " Move back to our original location.
    normal! `z
endfunction 

"clear all highlighting
function! ClearAllHi()
    for i in range(1,6)
        let mid = 77750 + i
        silent! call matchdelete(mid)
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>0 :call ClearAllHi()<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>1 :call HiInterestingWord(1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>2 :call HiInterestingWord(2)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>3 :call HiInterestingWord(3)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>4 :call HiInterestingWord(4)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>5 :call HiInterestingWord(5)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>6 :call HiInterestingWord(6)<cr>

hi def InterestingWord1 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#ffa724 ctermbg=214
hi def InterestingWord2 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#aeee00 ctermbg=154
hi def InterestingWord3 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#8cffba ctermbg=121
hi def InterestingWord4 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#b88853 ctermbg=137
hi def InterestingWord5 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#ff9eb8 ctermbg=211
hi def InterestingWord6 guifg=#000000 ctermfg=16 guibg=#ff2c4b ctermbg=195
"}}}
```

This allows you to press `<leader>` + `1-6` to high light word under cursor in different colors; pressing it twice to clear the highlighting. (You can change the color in `hi def...`) commands. And `<leader>+0` clear all highlights.

You can just put the codes in your vimrc to try.

It works like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking for: He basically wants a separate `SearchCurrent` highlight group in addition to `Search`.

Answer (score 1):

People have used [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/set-cursor-colour-different-when-on-a-highlighted-word) based on Damian Conway's talk

```
" Damian Conway's Die Blinkënmatchen: highlight matches                                                                                        
nnoremap <silent> n n:call HLNext(0.1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> N N:call HLNext(0.1)<cr>

function! HLNext (blinktime)
   let target_pat = '\c\%#'.@/
   let ring = matchadd('ErrorMsg', target_pat, 101)
   redraw
   exec 'sleep ' . float2nr(a:blinktime * 1000) . 'm'
   call matchdelete(ring)
   redraw
endfunction
```

---

But personally, I prefer a simple one, though this highlight whole line

```
"cursorline and it's highlighting                                                                                                              
set cursorline
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=green
```